# Simple clicker game

Tags: javascript, angular.js, file-structure

I have started my clicker game using angular.js about week ago. I have finished current functionality first night, but still have feeling of misunderstanding some basic approaches.

This is [sources root](https://github.com/koutoftimer/idle-miner/tree/replace-modals/src) on github. I'm trying to follow angular-code-style.

First of all, I'd like to hear some thoughts about code structure. I have 2 services: levels (responsible for storing information about mine level and workers) and resources (responsible for storing information related to any resources: ores, money, etc.). They are located in components module (which contains not refactored items, I just have no idea what to do with them).

Also, few words about ui-view and routing, related to my code, would be great.

This is file structure of my app:

> ```
> src/js/app
> ├── app.module.js
> ├── components
> │   ├── app.components.module.js
> │   ├── header
> │   │   ├── header.controller.js
> │   │   ├── header.directive.html
> │   │   └── header.directive.js
> │   └── mine
> │       ├── levels.service.js
> │       ├── mine.controller.js
> │       ├── mine.directive.html
> │       ├── mine.directive.js
> │       └── resources.service.js
> ├── mine
> │   ├── app.mine.module.js
> │   └── mine.template.html
> └── office
>     ├── app.office.module.js
>     ├── employee
>     │   ├── employee-center.controller.js
>     │   ├── employee-center.directive.html
>     │   ├── employee-center.directive.js
>     │   └── employee.template.html
>     ├── sell
>     │   ├── sell-center.controller.js
>     │   ├── sell-center.directive.html
>     │   ├── sell-center.directive.js
>     │   └── sell.template.html
>     └── upgrade
>         ├── upgrade-center.controller.js
>         ├── upgrade-center.directive.html
>         ├── upgrade-center.directive.js
>         └── upgrade.template.html
> ```

Here is my office routing config:

```js
angular
    .module('app.office', [
        'app.components',
        'ui.router'
    ])
    .config(ConfigureOffice);

ConfigureOffice.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];

function ConfigureOffice($stateProvider) {
    var office = {
            abstract: true,
            name: 'office',
            template: '<ui-view/>',
            title: 'Office',
            url: '/office'
        },
        officeSell = {
            name: 'sell-center',
            parent: office,
            templateUrl: 'js/app/office/sell/sell.template.html',
            title: 'Sell center',
            url: '/sell'
        },
        officeEmployee = {
            name: 'employee-center',
            parent: office,
            templateUrl: 'js/app/office/employee/employee.template.html',
            title: 'Employee center',
            url: '/employee'
        },
        officeUpgrade = {
            name: 'upgrade-center',
            parent: office,
            templateUrl: 'js/app/office/upgrade/upgrade.template.html',
            title: 'Upgrade center',
            url: '/upgrade'
        };

    $stateProvider
        .state(office)
        .state(officeSell)
        .state(officeEmployee)
        .state(officeUpgrade)
}
```

Currently, I have no office template, it is just a stub.